# Matched Filter Impulse Response

Tags: digital-communications, linear-systems

At the receiver end of a digital communication system, the matched filter is designed with impulse response matched to the effective signal that is given as : $$x_{(z,1)}^{*}(T_p-t)-x_{(z,0)}^{*}(T_p-t)$$

where $x_{(z,1)}(t)$ corresponds to a 1 and $x_{(z,0)}(t)$ corresponds to a zero.

But every where I check in the notes or the textbook I see that h(t) is gets conveniently modified from $$x_{(z,1)}^{*}(T_p-t)-x_{(z,0)}^{*}(T_p-t)$$

to

$$x_{(z,1)}^{*}(t)-x_{(z,0)}^{*}(t)$$

and the square of this is calculated as the euclidean distance.

I do not understand the rationale behind this.

Comment: Ah, I don't think I'd call what you have there a matched filter, but *pulse-shape decision* or something (I'm assuming $x_{(z,0)}$ and $x_{(z,1)}$ are pretty much orthogonal – otherwise writing it like this has little benefit over comparing the sampled output to constellation points)

Comment: point is – if my terminology would be different than yours, chances are I'm just misunderstanding you (a shame!). Could you explain what these $x$ actually are, and what do you do with its output?

Comment: $x_{(z,0)}$ and $x_{(z,1)}$ are the transmitted signals representing zero and one.... this is a single bit demodulator implementation...

Comment: but these two have the same wave form, right?

Comment: Hint: It is not the _square_ of the difference signal but rather the _energy_ that is a measure of the )squared) Euclldean distance, and the energy does.not depend on whether the signal is running backwards or forwards.